# Выдаёт ошибку Assets/Player.cs(43,59) Unexpected symbol `{'

Tags: c#

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyOne;
    [SerializeField] KeyCode keyTwo;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (keyOne)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity += moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (keyTwo)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity -= moveDirection;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.R)) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex);
        }
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Q)) 
    {
                SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex +1);
    }
}
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex +1);
    }
        if(this.CompareTag("Cube" && other.CompareTag("Cube")) {
                foreach(Activator button in FindObjectsOfType<Activator>())
                {
                    button.canPush = false;
                }
            }
            }
            private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
                if(this.CompareTag("Cube" && other.CompareTag("Cube"))
                    {
                        foreach(Activator button in FindObjectOfType<Activator>())
                        {
                            button.canPush = true;
    }
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: Предлагаю расценивать данного человека, как "вредителя" и спамера => [уверен, что есть и еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1241938/220553)

Comment: Приведите код в порядок, а то фигурные скобки черти как стоят. У вас 13 закрывающих скобок и 14 открывающих, одна где то лишняя.

Comment: Вот что бывает, когда пишешь по советам Хауди, а именно в блокноте, простите, в Sublime

Comment: @ГеннадийП все фигурные скобки у меня стоят вроде нормально. я из-за этого и обратился, я их и добавлял, и убирал, ничего не помогает. подчеркивает её и всё на этом...

Comment: @longvist Подсказка: Проблема ближе к концу кода. Форматируйте код нормально по-человечески, тогда сразу будет видно где проблема.